# git diff how many files of specific file extension (.js and not .test.js)

Tags: git

I want to know how many files of the extension `.js` are in my git diff.

So far I know I can do: `git diff -- '*.js'`, but this doesn't work because it also shows files that finish with `.test.js`, and I just want the ones which extension is `.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a tool like `grep` to filter out the names you do not want :

```
git diff --name-only -- '*.js' | grep -v 'test\.js$'
```